# Error "directive strict_import cannot be handled in cross-compilation mode"

Tags: macos, haskell

I try to build my project on M1 Mac (AARCH64) platform with `cabal`:

```
cabal --with-compiler="/Users/Me/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-9.2.3/bin/ghc" --store-dir=.cabal-store build
```

and it fails with error:

```
...
Failed to build bzlib-conduit-0.3.0.2.
Build log ( /Users/Me/.cabal/logs/ghc-9.2.3/bzlb-cndt-0.3.0.2-0a89fc9a.log
):
Configuring library for bzlib-conduit-0.3.0.2..
Preprocessing library for bzlib-conduit-0.3.0.2..
src/Data/Conduit/BZlib/Internal.hsc:8 directive strict_import cannot be handled in cross-compilation mode
Error: cabal: Failed to build bzlib-conduit-0.3.0.2
...
```

I tried to run `cabal` command in subshell running as `arch -x86_64 zsh`, but the result is the same.

How to fix it?

**EDIT:** I try to get x86_64 executable on this platform.

Answer (score 0):

After many experiments: unlike `stack` tool, `cabal` binary built **for x86_64** should be used. Everything else is the same. `arch -x86_64` is not required. But GHC binary should be right - built **for x86_64** platform as well.